# How to get a dataGridview columns style in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to know which style a column in a datagridview has ?
I need to know, what the style of `DataGridView` column is, something like:

```
bool bold = column1.bold; 
bool italic = column2.italic;
```

Comment: Explain more clearly please

Comment: Hossein, I wonder what is the style of the text from a cell of the datagridview. Something like: 
datagridview1.Columns[1] is bold, italic or underline.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a specific columns style, you can use it `Style` property.
You can use it like this :

```
var cellStyle = yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Style;
```

If you need to get the font property associated with a column you need to use the `Font` property of the selected column style.
So to hit the nail on the head you would want to use some thing like this :

```
    bool bold = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font.Bold;
    bool italic = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Style.Font.Italic;
```